# an irrelevant error with a (if) condition: syntax error on token invalid character, delete this token

Tags: java

i was working on a Java code that i faced this error:
syntax error on token invalid character delete this token
i don't have any idea how to solve this problem.
the original code:

```
if ((base[i - 1][j] != 0) &&‌ (base[i - 1][j] != c))//the error is on this line
{
    for (int p = 1; p < i; p++) {
        if (base[i - p - 1][j] != 0) {
            break;
        }
        if (base[i - p - 1][j] != c) {
            break;
            location[0] = i - p - 1;
            location[1] = j;
        }
        if (location != null) {
            int[] temploc1 = new int[2];
            int[] temploc2 = new int[2];
            temploc1[0] = i;
            temploc1[1] = j;
            temploc2[0] = i - p - 1;
            temploc2[1] = j;
            paint(temploc1, temploc2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what the type of `c` and `base` array ??

Comment: Can you provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the compiler error? The error might actually be a result of the code on the previous line, which you aren't showing.

Comment: which is the invalid character?

Comment: There's not enough information here for us to diagnose the problem. Please provide the definitions of `base`, `i`, `j`, and `c`.

Comment: int c=0;
  if (turn%2==0 )
   c = 1;
  if (turn%2==1 )
   c = 2;

Comment: Just to rule out invisible characters (happens when you copy and paste from other sources) just retype the line letter by letter in a new line and replace it.

Comment: int[][] base = new int[8][8];

Answer (score 4):

You have an invalid invisible character between `&&` and the following space (unicode = 8204):

```
if ((base[i-1][j]!=0) &&‌ (base[i-1][j]!=c))//the error is on this line
                        ^
```

It works fine if you delete and retype `&&` (including the space):

```
if ((base[i-1][j]!=0) && (base[i-1][j]!=c))//the error is on this line
```

Comment: Do you mean the ampersand or the space after the ampersand?

Comment: @crush it's between the `&&` and the space after `&&`

Comment: I am detecting a zero-width character. So it's not the space itself.

Comment: Maybe it's before the space I added, since it's a zero-width character.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik yes you're right, it's between the `&&` and the space.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
        int i = 1;
    int[][] base;
    int j = 1;
    int c = 1;
    int base1 = base[i - 1][j ];
    int base2 = base[i - 1][j];
    if (base1!= 0) {
        if (base2!= c) {
        for (int p = 1; p < i; p++) {
            if (base[i - p - 1][j] != 0) {
                break;
            }
            int[] location;
            if (base[i - p - 1][j] != c) {
                break;
                location[0] = i - p - 1;
                location[1] = j;
            }
            if (location != null) {
                int[] temploc1 = new int[2];
                int[] temploc2 = new int[2];
                temploc1[0] = i;
                temploc1[1] = j;
                temploc2[0] = i - p - 1;
                temploc2[1] = j;
                paint(temploc1, temploc2);
            }
        }
        }
    }
```